# A curve not homotopic to constant path but index of every point is zero.

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I want to find a curve which is not homotopic to constant path but the index of every point not on the curve is zero. Here the domain is an open subset of Complex Plane.I was unable to find any such curve, So if anyone can give an example it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: In some open subset of the plane, or where?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz in Complex plane

Comment: In the complex plane, every curve is homotopic to a constant one.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz is it possible in an open subset of Complex Plane

Comment: Yes, the complex plane without two points will work. Go around the first, then the second and then along the same paths around the first backwards and around the second backwards.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz I am convinced it is not homotopic to constant path but how do we show it?

Comment: Not without some theory, I fear. "Fundamental group of the wedge of two circles" would be something to look at.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz thanks a lot

Comment: You are welcome. Apologies for not writing a proper answer, I was on my iPad ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One example is the Pochhammer Contour.
You can read about it here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_contour